# Can web application be considered part of client/server architecture?

Tags: web, architecture, client-server, software-design

I am doing a research on client/server architecture and web applications. I've been reading different thoughts and suggestions around the web. Some saying that web applications are not considered client/server architecture apps while others are saying the exact opposite. I was wondering what is actually the right thing and if someone can provide in depth explanation that would be highly appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the architecture/design of your web application(s). The rule of thumb would be: The client application has to be another piece of software than the (resource) server. There is no "one right way" to design a client/server architecture.

The most common implementations for web based applications are MVC (Model View Controller and SPAs (Single Page Applications).

[MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) applications (like ASP.NET or ZendFramework) are applications that are booth rendering the client and handling the business logic in the backend and are not based on a client/server model. (An action in a controller handles a request, loads some data and renders an HTML view as the response).

But: If your MVC Application is acting as a proxy calling a "remote" web service internally (via SOAP or whatever), it should be considered a client application.
As an example: A CRM system is running in an intranet network and provides a data-services for desktop clients. You could write a web application that displays data from those services which is then another client application.

---

The [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) architecture requires the separation of the server from the frontend, the SPA being the frontend, which in turn is the client application. With this requirement you are basically already implementing a client/server architecture. Let's say an AngularJS frontend and the backend could be a REST service (like ASP.NET WebAPI or Lumen).

The choice of where you host the client application does not affect the client/server architecture, since the applications are still separated on execution: the browser executes the JavaScript SPA on the device of the visitor and calls the service in some data center.

Comment: Fazeksas That helps very much! Just to clarify - Lets say Im building web application (AngularJS/React/Etc)  which front-end handles operations such as writing data in   MySQL database hosted in a cloud & based on that the server will do something with the data like sending alerts etc. Is that client/server architecture application or something else?

Comment: If you are sending the data directly to the database then i would say it's not a client/server architecture. That's because i separate my data sources from the business logic when designing an application. I guess the application that sends the alerts does so by polling, that would make that application a standalone application.
If you are sending the data from your frontend to a server which then saves the data to a datastore and sends alerts, it would be a client/server architecture.

Comment: Yes what I meant was sending data from the front-end to a server which would save the data into a database & than the server would do something else like send alerts or whatever back is client/server architecture right?

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to explain this! Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Web application is a part of client-server architecture. Any implementations have always two or more tiers, so two or more process communicate each other.
You may take a look on my old presentation "[Architecture of enterprise (automated) information system - Layers and levels](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/287201275_Architecture_of_enterprise_automated_information_system_-Layers_and_levels_-MDA_MDD_approach_-Relation_to_the_software_development_life-cycle)" that shows different client-server architectures including web application case (the slide "Tiers are physical layers (examples)" shows examples).